# Open app from another app with Xamarin.Forms and MvvmCross UWP

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Opening app from another app can be done like:

```
public async Task<bool> LaunchUriAsync(string objectNumber)
{
  var option = new LauncherOptions();
  option.UI.PreferredPlacement = Placement.Right;
  option.DesiredRemainingView = ViewSizePreference.UseMore;
  return await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(buildObjectAccessUri(objectNumber), option);
}


private static Uri buildObjectAccessUri(string objectId)
{
  return new Uri(String.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", "myapp", "data", objectId), UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

in a Command I do:

```
await MyLauncherService.LaunchUriAsync("whatever");
```

and in opened application I have a custom start

```
public class CustomAppStart : MvxAppStart
{
    protected override async Task NavigateToFirstViewModel(object hint = null)
    {
        // hint here is type of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs`
    }
}
```

Seems that object `hint` is type of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs`

The `App.xaml.cs` of UWP project:

```
sealed partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }  
}

public abstract class UwpApp : MvxApplication<Setup<Core.App>, Core.App>
{
    private ILoggerService mLoggerService;
    public UwpApp()
    {
      UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
      {
        mLoggerService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ILoggerService>();
        if (mLoggerService == null)
        {
          return;
        }
        mLoggerService.Fatal("Unhandled exception!", args.Exception);
      };

      DebugSettings.BindingFailed += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.Message);
      TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
      {
        mLoggerService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ILoggerService>();
        if (mLoggerService == null)
        {
          return;
        }
        foreach (var ex in args.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
          mLoggerService.Error(ex.Message + " StackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        args.SetObserved();
      };
      Suspending += OnSuspending;
      ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Auto;
    }
    protected override void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
      var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
      deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Why I got that ?

I expected to be string ...

Where is the mistake ?

I'm using latest version of xamarin and mvvm cross

Comment: I guess that is what you pass in as hint in your App.xaml.cs file where you set up MvvmCross? You probably need to add more detail about what is going on in that file, for someone to help.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I updated my post with Setup in `App.xaml.cs`

Comment: Override `GetAppStartHint` in your `UwpApp` and process the hint as needed and return a string if that is what you expect. See: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Uap/Views/MvxApplication.cs#L83

Comment: @Cheesebaron: please post it as answer... It solve my problem, will accept it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MvxApplication` you can override `GetAppStartHint` to process the object coming into that method and return a string as you expect.

Something like:

```
public abstract class UwpApp : MvxApplication<Setup<Core.App>, Core.App>
{
    protected override object GetAppStartHint(object hint = null)
    {
        // process hint
        //return string
    }
}
```